# Как интегрировать Яндекс.Вебмастер в 1С-Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс, яндекс-вебмастер

Мне нужно при добавлении елемента каталога, добавлять описание каждого нового елемента в Оригинальные тексты с помощью API, которое предоставляет Яндекс. Но я не знаю, каким образом можно интегрировать Яндекс.Вебмастер в 1С-Битрикс Управление сайтом версии 11.5.11.

Можете пожалуйста помочь с этим?

Answer (score 0):

Есть готовый модуль для передачи "оригинальных текстов" в Яндекс.Вебмастер.

http://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/webkernel.originaltext/

Comment: Готовый модуль есть начиная с 14-ой версии продукта. В 11-ой версии такого модуля еще нет.

Comment: Тогда посмотрите как работает модуль и сделайте аналогичный функционал под свою старую версию ядра, используя официальный API Яндекс.Вебмастер.
https://tech.yandex.ru/webmaster/doc/dg/reference/host-original-texts-post-docpage/